# can't ssh into docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, docker

Say I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server \
    && mkdir /var/run/sshd \
    && echo 'root:root' | chpasswd \
    && sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
    && service ssh start
```

I create a Docker instance from this Dockerfile thusly:

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -t -d --privileged test bash
docker exec -it {whatever} bash
```

After that, I try to SSH into the machine and it doesn't work:

```
root@5e3395ae4b64:/# ssh 127.0.0.1
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

If I do `service ssh start` again it works but idk why I need to do that since I'm already doing it in the Dockerfile.

Anyway, after I do `service ssh start`, password authentication doesn't work:

```
The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:hQcDdJFTmCZvhJzWbbis5OvCiqx1eagG0b6SD83GbJo.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
```

(I manually typed root as the password)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up getting this working by just creating a new user:

```
    && useradd --create-home --base-dir /home newuser \
    && echo "newuser:newuser" | chpasswd \
```

Answer (score 0):

I think root shell is disabled. You can see it in

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

if its accessible.
Try it and tell me if there is a shell for user root.

Then can you test a

```
netstat -an | grep 22
```

To see in which hosts the sshd is listening. If you don't see 127.0.0.1

Try to see if in the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** you are using **AllowUsers** directive it takes precedence to **PermitRootLogin**.

And  just see if this line  of your DockerFile is applied in your file:

```
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` - that's what /etc/passwd says.

Comment: I am happy that you have found a solution :) (can't comment your answer) - don't forget to accept your solution.